# Removing column in field seperated file using scripting

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

The files is seperated by | pipe symbol

myfile.txt

```
Hello|how|are|you|hope|you|are|doing|fine
Lilly|jasmine|rose|sunflower|nightfire|flowers
```

I want to remove columns greater than 3. I want result set as

```
Hello|how|are
Lilly|jasmine|rose
```

Using unix commands in unix shell scritping.

Comment: What did you already try and what problems did you encounter? At Stack Exchange sites you should first try to resolve the problem by yourself before asking.

Comment: I have got the answer! and answered it below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cut -d'|' -f1-3 myfile
```

This will be easier solution for this. Works fine!

Comment: I would think this is as as easy a solution as this. Why would it be easier if it this and this are the same?

Comment: @VRVigneshwara; Didn't you ask for a sed or awk solution?

Answer (score 1):

Using `OFS` and `FS` (Output) Field Separator, simply print the first 3 columns

```
$ awk  'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"}{print $1,$2,$3}' file.txt
Hello|how|are
Lilly|jasmine|rose
```

Using sed, keep only the first two "`|[everything that's not |]`":

```
~$ sed 's/\(\(|[^|]*\)\{2\}\).*/\1/' file.txt
Hello|how|are
Lilly|jasmine|rose
```

Comment: For example i have used 3 columns I have actually 17 columns to be selected as $1$2 ... $17.

Comment: @VIGNESH12990 when asking a question, you need to give an example that reflects what you are actually trying to do. Please edit your question and make it show what you are really asking. There is a _huge_ difference between selecting 3 fields and 17.

Comment: @terdon; There *may* be a difference, depending on the proposed solution. (See my answer for an `awk` solution where it doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 1):

In `awk` it suffices to do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}; NF=3' myfile.txt
```

(If you have 17 columns, as noted in some comment, just change the `3` to `17`.)